# Is there any memory issue to use of static in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use static in my react-native project. I am not sure about memory uses
so it will take extra memory or any memory leakage will happen in my project.

Comment: Hard to know without more context.   Will it leak memory?  Maybe.  Will it matter?  Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: Trying to create a separate class for API calling and make the method static.

class RequestData {
  static getAll(){
      return fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
  }
}
export default RequestData

Like this.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a memory issue but as with all code elements, more lines of code (especially heavy ones) will lead to slightly more RAM usage. This isn't an issue, especially if you're using something like expo or p5.js where the online editor uses resources from the server and not your home computer. More RAM is good to have, especially with multitasking, but it's not exactly a necessity. If you have 8-12GB RAM or more, you should be fine with coding projects like these even when hosting from a laptop.

There's probably little to no memory leak risk, but that's the same with everything right, every project has that risk but it mostly works out fine. You should be good and if not, just try optimising your code. One method that I always use is splitting complex statements into simpler ones which work the same. It increases the lines of code but makes it easier to debug. Then I revert it back to the original having found the bug and fix it.

Good luck!